# Custom headers get added to Access-Control-Request-Headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, angular-http

I am trying to add a custom header to my angular js GET request as below:

```
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : s,
        headers : {
        "partnerId" : 221,
         "partnerKey" : "heeHBcntCKZwVsQo"
        }
    })
```

But the issue is the headers are getting added to Access-Control-Request-Headers as below and I am getting **403 Forbidden** response:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:50.0)
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/ *;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: partnerid,partnerkey
Origin: http://localhost:8080
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

I also tried below changes but no luck

```
return $http.get(s, {
    headers : {
        'partnerId' : 221,
        'partnerKey': 'heeHBcntCKZwVsQo'
        }
    })
```

In other related answers in SO I saw that the header partnerId and partnerKey need to be enabled in server side. But I am able to add these custom headers in POSTMAN client and other POST clients and able to get the expected response. So I guess I am missing something. Can someone guide me in this. Thanks in advance

Edit: One more thing I noted is that partnerId is replaced as partnerid while passing in the request. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I ran into something similar where custom headers were added to Access-Control-Request-Headers. Turned out I mistyped the url and it was pointing to an api that did not exist. Problem went away when i fixed the url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add any headers to a scripted cross-origin request other than any [CORS-safelisted request-headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header), it triggers browsers to first [do a CORS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

There is no way to prevent users’ browsers from doing that CORS preflight (though there are ways to get around it locally in your own browser when doing testing; for example, by using Postman).

So for users to be able to use a Web app of yours that makes scripted cross-origin requests with custom headers, the server to which those cross-origin requests go needs to be CORS-aware.

The reason Postman can make such requests without causing a preflight is, Postman’s not a browser engine—it's an extension that’s not restricted by the same-origin policy, so doesn’t need CORS.

Postman can basically do whatever `curl` or other such tools can do, but just within a browser UI for convenience. It’s otherwise bypassing normal Web-security features built into browsers.

Comment: Hi @sideshowbarker Thanks for the prompt reply. So you mean to say that I need to make changes in the server side to accept the headers partnerId and partnerKey?

Comment: @SathiyaNarayanan Yes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers (about the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header) for starters.